# Add custom button to ExtJS HtmlEditor component

Tags: button, extjs, toolbar

I tried to add custom button to my HtmlEditor in ExtJs but no luck:

```
            var toolbar = this.getToolbar();
            var editor = this;
            toolbar.add({
                xtype: 'button',
                itemId: 'Blackening',
                enableOnSelection: true,
                tooltip: {
                    title: 'blackening',
                    text: 'text blackening'
                },
                text: 'blackening',
                handler: function() { 
                    var text = editor.getDoc().getSelection().toString();
                    editor.relayCmd('InsertHTML', '<span style="border-bottom: 3px dotted red;">' + text + '</span>');
                },
            });
```

Its working perfect but when i mark the text (that I set "blackening" on it) its not enabling my button in the toolbar (its not recognized that i used it on mark text) and if i click again on the button it doesnt remove the "blackening" from the mark text.

what can i do ?

thanks a lot

Comment: Can you share a fiddle with working example.

Comment: @Tejas http://jsfiddle.net/uLty7rsx/

Comment: Now can you explain required output wrt your fiddle ?

Comment: when i click in the most right button (blackening) its add 3 pixels red bottom to the mark text like i expected but when i click again its not remove the border... actually its not set a pressed affect on the blackening button. @Tejas

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to change the CSS property of a editor but this will not remove the blackening of text.To remove the selection the logic is get the length of text entered and selection range of text (length,length).